# Query not showing output

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch data from both table. UID in hall_booking table is foreign key and uid in registration is primary key.

```
     <?php
    $bid=$_REQUEST['book_id'];
    $uid=$_REQUEST['id']; 
    echo $sel="select * from hall_booking INNER JOIN registration ON  
    hall_booking.uid=registration.uid WHERE  hall_booking.booking_id=$bid AND  
     registration.uid=$uid";
    $res=mysql_query($sel) or die(mysql_error());

    $row=mysql_num_rows($res);
    while($fet=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {?>
    <center><form name="details" method="post" >
     <table border="0" cellspacing="8px" id="table">
     <tr><td>First Name : </td><td><?php echo $fet['first_name']; ?></td></tr>
     <tr><td>Last Name : </td><td><?php echo $fet['last_name'];?></td></tr>
     <tr><td>Address : </td><td><?php echo $fet['address'];?></td></tr>
     <tr><td>Contact no : </td><td><?php echo $fet['mobile_no'];?></td></tr>
     <tr><td>E-mail ID : </td><td><?php echo $fet['email_id'];?></td></tr>
     <tr><td>Status : </td><td><?php echo $fet['purpose']; ?></td>

      <tr><td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px"><center><a              
      href="show_plot_booking.php"> &lt;&lt;Back </a></center></td></tr>
      </table>
      </form></center>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Show your data in your table. Sow your actual query with value of `$uid` and `$bid` in it.

Comment: did you try this query directly on mysql ?

Comment: If you have no error shown, your query is running but not returning any records (maybe because your JOIN conditions are wrong). Like @AbhikChakraborty said, try this in your phpmyadmin first.

Answer (score 0):

check your `$bid` and `$uid` is not empty

try to quote your query var

```
$sel="select * from hall_booking INNER JOIN registration ON  
    hall_booking.uid=registration.uid WHERE  hall_booking.booking_id='$bid' AND  
     registration.uid='$uid'";
```

also change to assoc

```
while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
```

also better to use count number of rows or your query return rows

```
$row=mysql_num_rows($res);

if($row > 0) {
  // do your stuff
}
else {
 echo 'echo no rows found';
}
```